# Laravel accessible only in incognito

Tags: laravel

I have a current Laravel site staging where I can't access in chrome and tells me **"This site can't be reached"**, but when I tried to access in an incognito window, it works. I am not sure what happened, and I already try to clear the cache, cookies and etc. but still didn't work.

This is the link to my site: https://staging.normrentals.com.au/

Comment: did you clear browser cache ? (ctrl+F5)

Comment: I already run artisan optimize: clear, but still didn't work

Comment: and clear my browser cache and cookies, yet still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to force clear browser cache. CMD + SHIFT + R, CTRL + F5 etc.

Comment: I already force clear my browser cache, but still didn't work

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem is related to the browser.  You can test it with another browser such as Opera, Firefox, Safari. If there was a problem, you would also get an error in the incognito tab.

Comment: Yes, I think it's on my browser, I tried in incognito and other browsers it works. But I got confused why is it still not working in my chrome browser even though I already cleared caches & cookies and etc.

Comment: Would you try this? Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#dns and press the "Clear host cache" button.

Comment: nothing happens when I clicked the Clear host cache button.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens, I try to access it today and it works now, I think this is on my chrome browser problem